Deploying a program to mainnet seems impossible?
I have no issue deploying to testnet and devnet, but everything I've tried to get the program to deploy to mainnet using the CLI ends up with it hanging.
Has anyone deployed a program recently (April 2024) and have any tips?
I tried using --with-compute-unit-price but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Could just be due to network congestion
you'll also have to consider that Mainnet transactions might experience higher execution costs due to network activity. You can try using the 'solana fee calculator' command to get a more accurate fee estimate before deployment.

They generate the most recent prioritized-fee deployment commands here https://solana.gears.bot/deploy-cmd. Give it a try guys.

@Tu Phan --with-compute-unit-price and --max-sign-attempts arguments doesn't work any more. error: Found argument '--with-compute-unit-price' which wasn't expected, or isn't valid in this context.
